# C# Saving ListViewItem: SubItems and Tags to textfile

Tags: c#, winforms, listviewitem

I am working on Winforms project for myself, basically I have a form with a ListView(listView1), I have many many controls and subforms and whatnot on/in this project, anyway my goal originally was to save the data entered in the ListViewItem to a ".txt" file with each item separated by a comma(,).

Originally this was working great, however i have since adapted my App to also add data to each listView1.SelectedItem[i].Tag", which also works great but i forgot to re-look over at the saving side of things...

So i have this formula which was submitted by someone on StackOverflow(sorry i can't whom it was nor remember/find the link):

```
        private StringBuilder ReadingListView()
    {
        string delimiter = ",";
        List<string> values;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            values = new List<string>();
            for (int j = 0; j < listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Count; j++)
            {
                values.Add(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[j].Text);
            }

            sb.AppendLine(string.Join(delimiter, values.ToArray()));
        }
        return sb;
    }
```

This works really well and it saves me a lot of time, can someone please give an example of how to adapt this to also save the "listView1.Items[i].Tag" ? I cannot get my brain to function and workout why I can't adapt this to also support adding the "Tag" its something I have been stuck on for a few hours now, I know there is a simple solution but ARGH! I keep trying many methods and can't work out how to do it.

Comment: I was using something along those lines but it doesn't add the 'Tag' in the txt file in correct order: values.Add(listView1.Items[i].Tag.ToString()); Just adding that under values.Add(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[j].Text); wont put it in the textfile in correct order, it will also keep repeating "Tag" same number of times each subitem appears because of the loop. Adding it underneath the 'for loop' works great, it adds one 'Tag' to end of sript, downfall is i want it to be the second item in the script not the last.

Comment: so, what is expected order of data? Can you give some example; how does the listItems look like and how the txt file should look like?

Comment: So i just decided to add the specific items in an array so i can have them in order on the txt file.

Answer (score 1):

My brain just woke up, i have realized i just need to make an array in order of the way i want the data to be saved in the text file and changed the for loop to be less complex:

```
        private StringBuilder ReadingListView()
    {
        string delimiter = ",";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            string[] arr = new string[5];
            arr[0] = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[0].Text;
            arr[1] = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text;
            arr[2] = listView1.Items[i].Tag.ToString();
            arr[3] = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text;
            arr[4] = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[4].Text;
            sb.AppendLine(string.Join(delimiter, arr.ToArray()));
        }
        return sb;
    }
```

Thanks for trying to help @Nino, if you have a better solution please let me know.

Comment: that's it, there's no need for better solution :)

Comment: @Nino I just realised... If i do the above what if the array has nothing inside it? It saves fine but if i want to open the txt file and restore these arrays to the listview the arrays would be re-arranged if any of them were empty... How would you use the AppendLine to also add white-space for those blank items?

Comment: if array is empty, StringBuilder string would look like `,,,,` (empty strings delimited with commas). But, to replace empty strings with spaces, you can do something like this: `arr[0] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[0].Text) ? " " : listView1.Items[i].SubItems[0].Text;` or you can write your extension method.

Comment: @Nino Nice haha, i was thinking like:               for (int ii = 0; ii < listView1.Items.Count; ii++)
                    if (arr[ii] == null || arr[ii].Length == 0)
                    {
                        string blankArray = "NO_DATA";
                        arr[ii] = blankArray;
                    }

Comment: consider serialization as right approach for saving data to file. Check out this [article](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/483055/xml-serialization-and-deserialization-part)

Comment: Nice, that would be much more appropriate i believe, i will surely be implementing this to my project and altering it a bit to match my needs after i have finished the GUI, many thanks @Nino